# How to use AVG and COUNT in union of JOIN and LEFT JOIN tables MySQL | PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of products, where I am calling additional data, such as the category, the author and, now I want to pretend to show the ratings.

I was doing the following inside a `While`

```
                $stmtR = $con->prepare("SELECT AVG(rating) AS avg_rating,
                                                COUNT(*) valuations
                                        FROM tbl_ratings
                                        WHERE id_course=?");
                $stmtR->bind_param("i",$id_course);
                $stmtR->execute();
                $stmtR->bind_result($avg_rating,$valuations);
                while ($stmtR->fetch()) {
                    $avg_print = number_format($avg_rating,1);
                        echo '<div class="review flex">
                            <div class="total">
                                <span>'.$avg_print.'</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="rating">
                                '.display_star_print($avg_print).'
                            </div>
                            <div class="valuations"><span>('.$valuations.')</span></div>
                        </div>';
                }
                $stmtR->close();
```

But taking advantage of the fact that I am calling all the data from table union, I am trying the following, to avoid making a query inside `While`

```
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT co.id_course,
                                    au.author,
                                    ca.program_lang,
                                    co.study_program,
                                    co.launch,
                                    co.start_date,
                                    co.release_date,
                                    co.title_course,
                                    co.subtitle_course,
                                    co.price_old,
                                    co.price,
                                    co.url,
                                    //(AVG(ra.rating) AS ra.avg_rating,
                                    COUNT(*) ra.valuations) this add additional to avoid doing a query within a loop, obviously without parentheses
                            FROM tbl_courses co
                            JOIN tbl_category ca ON co.category = ca.id_category
                            LEFT JOIN tbl_author au ON co.author = au.id_user
                            LEFT JOIN tbl_ratings ra ON co.id_course = ra.id_course
                            WHERE ca.program_lang = ? AND co.active = ?
                            ORDER BY co.id_course DESC
                            LIMIT ?");
    ...
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                $stmtR = $con->prepare("SELECT AVG(rating) AS avg_rating,
                                                COUNT(*) valuations
                                        FROM tbl_ratings
                                        WHERE id_course=?");
                $stmtR->bind_param("i",$id_course);
                $stmtR->execute();
                $stmtR->bind_result($avg_rating,$valuations);
                while ($stmtR->fetch()) {
                    $avg_print = number_format($avg_rating,1);
                        echo '<div class="review flex">
                            <div class="total">
                                <span>'.$avg_print.'</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="rating">
                                '.display_star_print($avg_print).'
                            </div>
                            <div class="valuations"><span>('.$valuations.')</span></div>
                        </div>';
                }
                $stmtR->close();
    }
```

But this does not print anything to me, which is the correct way to use it, I suppose that in the `COUNT` it may be affecting because I don't know how to tell it what to count but from the table `tbl_ratings ra`

The error:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=682257fd1529d3f58b4d7c6a43aa9f67

Comment: @Strawberry What more clear example friend, I am saying that to avoid making a query within a cycle, (even attached examples) I want to pass that query in union of tables, at the end of the day I am passing data from `tbl_courses` to` Where` conditions of the table `tbl_ratings`

Comment: Explaining the link seems to defeat the point of providing the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of avg or count with no group by says you want a single summary row returned, with the count and average of all ratings for all courses.  It looks like you just want to add a

```
GROUP BY co.id_course
```

before the ORDER BY, so you get one row for each course, with the au.* and co.* fields for that course and the avg and count for the ratings for that course.

Comment: This does not work friend, the `AVG` and, the` COUNT` belongs to the table `tbl_ratings` as you can see in the first example what I do not want is to do that within the cycle where I already have my queries with several unions already , so to avoid that, I want to also join the table `tbl_ratings` to my second example, again to avoid doing an additional query within the loop.

Comment: I understand all that, I think.  Please explain why it doesn't work?  Edit your question to show what you are trying and what results you get and what results you expect.

Comment: It doesn't print anything to me, I don't get an error, specifically friend, how do I let you know that the `AVG` and the  `COUNT(*)` belong to the `tbl_ratings` table?

Comment: that's not how you should think of it, though that is the effect of a group by.  the join with no group by or aggregate functions in the select would produce one row for each rating for each course.  adding the group by makes it one row for each course instead, and makes the avg and count be for all the grouped together rows that would have been produced without the group by, which is all the ratings (though the count(*) will produce 1 even if there are no ratings; if you want 0 for a course with no ratings, you need count(ra.valuations) or some other non-null field in ra.)

Comment: can't help with the not printing anything unless you show your data.  Try entering some create table and insert statements and the select in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 that demonstrate your problem and add the resulting link to your question.

Comment: It shows me an error: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=02c897de81e874c330b8820f47d917f3 and https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=682257fd1529d3f58b4d7c6a43aa9f67

Comment: I already fixed it, apart from what you mentioned, I had to replace this: `AVG (ra.rating) AS ra.avg_rating, COUNT (*) ra.valuations` with this:` AVG (ra.rating) AS avg_rating, COUNT (*) valuations`

Comment: I only have one problem, it is that the `valuations` is telling me data on a product that has no valuation

Comment: right, if you want to include special characters like `.` in a column alias (or most other places) you need to quote in backticks, so ``AVG(ra.rating) AS `ra.valuations` `` or just `AVG(ra.rating) AS valuations`

Comment: as mentioned 6 comments above, use `count(ra.valuations)` (or some other non-null column in the ratings table) to report 0 when there are no ratings.